# How to customise the ghost-text (drag item name) with AgGrid

Tags: drag-and-drop, ag-grid

As per title, is there a way to customise the "ghost text" with the (unmanaged) row-dragging implementation in [AgGrid](https://ag-grid.com) **via the API**?

[image: drag ghost text]

Comment: Note that I'm using both grouping and drag and drop features of AgGrid w/ the 'groupRemoveSingleChildren' flag enabled. It seems to be using the last entry in the (grouping) data path (getDataPath callback).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can now use colDef.rowDragText to set a callback function to set the dragged text.

https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-row-dragging/#custom-row-drag-text

Comment: Thank you for the answer, it helped me too. Any idea how can I render an HTML element instead of text? (I want to make a custom ghost drag element).
Tried this and the text is rendered as-is :
`<div [innerHTML]=${params.rowNode.data.RULE_NAME}></div>`

Comment: You're welcome. I answered on your question.

Answer (score 2):

I found workaround using valueGetter property to change this text.
Example configuration of column:

```
private dragDropColumn= {
    rowDrag: true,
    ...
    valueGetter: (params) => {
      return params.data.myVariableFromRow;
    }
  }
```

Hope this helps

Comment: This is the way to go, very surprised this isn't documented anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

`onRowDragEnter event`,
you could search for the ghost element 
and then append your custom class to it.

`document.querySelectorAll('.ag-dnd-ghost')[0]
.classlist.add('my-custom-ghost-element');`

Dont forget to follow the hierarchy of classes, otherwise you would end up using `!important` in the custom class :-)

// For  updating text

search for the element with `className` `ag-dnd-ghost-label`

`document.querySelectorAll('.ag-dnd-ghost-label')[0]
.innerHTML = 'your_custom_text';`

Ghost element is added only during drag, once drag is ended, its removed from dom by Ag-Grid.

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I didn't state it in the question, but I was hoping for a documented / API-based approach (rather than relying on the internals of AgGrid)

Answer (score 0):

I've researched this and there is nothing built in to ag-grid.  I accomplished this by attaching to the onRowDragMove and onRowDragMove events.

I set a class variable 'isRowDragging' to only do this once while dragging.

I use the Angular Renderer2 class (this.ui) to find and update the Element of the ghost label.

All of this is available with vanilla javascript or other supported ag-grid frameworks.

```
this.gridOptions.onRowDragMove = (params: RowDragMoveEvent) => {
    const overNode = params.overNode;
    const movingNode = params.node;

    if (!this.isRowDragging) {
        this.isRowDragging = true;

        if (!movingNode.isSelected()) {
            if (params.event && params.event.ctrlKey) {
                movingNode.setSelected(true);
            }

            if (params.event && !params.event.ctrlKey) {
                movingNode.setSelected(true, true);
            }
        }

        let labelText: string = '';
        const selectedNodes = this.gridOptions.api.getSelectedNodes();

        if (selectedNodes.length === 1) {
            labelText = selectedNodes[0].data.Name;
        }
        else {
            const guids: string[] = [];
            let folderCount: number = 0;
            let docCount: number = 0;

            selectedNodes.forEach((node: RowNode) => {

                guids.push((node.data.FolderGuid || node.data.DocumentGuid).toLowerCase());

                if (node.data.FolderGuid !== undefined) {
                    folderCount++;
                }
                else {
                    docCount++;
                }
            });

            if (folderCount === 1) {
                labelText = '1 folder';
            }
            else if (folderCount > 1) {
                labelText = folderCount + ' folders';
            }

            if (docCount === 1) {
                labelText += (labelText !== '' ? ', ' : '') + '1 document';
            }
            else if (docCount > 1) {
                labelText += (labelText !== '' ? ', ' : '') + docCount + ' documents';
            }
        }

        console.log(this.ui.find(document.body, '.ag-dnd-ghost').outerHTML);

        this.ui.find(document.body, '.ag-dnd-ghost-label').innerHTML = labelText;
    }
}

this.gridOptions.onRowDragEnd = (event: RowDragEndEvent) => {
    this.isRowDragging = false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am using ag-grid with react and using cellRendererFramework property of ColDef to use custom react component, my value getter returns object, so when I start dragging I am getting [object object], I added toString method to returning object and did the trick, below is my sample code

```
const col1 = {
rowDrag: true,
...
valueGetter: (params) => {
  const {id, name} = params.data;
  return {id, name, toString: () => name}; // so when dragging it will display name property
}
```

}